# Javascript, window.addEventListener('blur') won't work

Tags: javascript

I would like to set a timeout javascript.

If the browser stays on browser, it redirect to fallbackLink.

If the browser loses the focus, it expire the timeout and doesn't redirect to fallbackLink

here is my script.

```
<script>
(function(){

var fallbackLink = '<?=$info['failed_url']?>'+window.location.search+window.location.hash;

var isiOS = navigator.userAgent.match('iPad') || navigator.userAgent.match('iPhone'),
    isAndroid = navigator.userAgent.match('Android');

if (isiOS) {
  document.getElementById('loader').src = '<?=$info['scheme']?>://'+window.location.search+window.location.hash;
}
var countdown = window.setTimeout(function (){
           window.location.replace(fallbackLink);
    }, 1000);

    window.addEventListener("blur", function(){
                window.clearTimeout(countdown)
    }, false);

  })();
</script>
```

Somehow it does redirect even though the browser is out of focus.

I need to stop to redirect when the screen doesn't focus on web browser.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the typo (`fucntion` instead of `function`) present in your original code?

Comment: I changed the typo, but it still doesn't pause the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the only way to handle `blur` event on `window` objects is using `window.onblur`.
You can try to keep old handlers doing this:

```
var concatFunctions = function(fn1, fn2){
  return function(){
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
    try{
      fn1.apply(this, args);
    } catch(err) { console.error(err); }
    fn2.apply(this, args);
  };
};
window.onblur = concatFunction(window.onblur, function(){
  // do your stuff
});
```

Comment: Don't know why It didn't works as expected back to 2014. I've tested today and it worked on chromium browser version 74, @Michael